# The Hat in the equation not on the middle of the Symbol

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I tried the \hat to always worked good but in this equation it's not middled and looks bad

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{authblk} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx,kantlipsum,setspace}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\captionsetup{font={stretch=1.0}}  %% this affects both figure and table
\setstretch{1.0}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage[left=6cm,top=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\newcommand\seqwlimits[3]{\{#1\}_{\mathstrut#2}^{\mathstrut#3}}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle 
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

        \thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{equation}
Q_{Ind}(\pi_{01} = \pi_{11}) = -2\log\left(\frac{(1-\hat{\pi_1})^{T_{00}} \hat{\pi_1}^{T_{01}} (1-\hat{\pi_1})^{T_{10}} \hat{\pi_1}^{T_{11}}     }{(1-\hat{\pi_01})^{T_{00}} \hat{\pi_{01}}^{T_{01}} (1-\hat{\pi_{11}})^{T_{10}} \hat{\pi_{11}}^{T_{11}}}\right)
\end{equation}
\end {document}
```

Comment: Try `\hat{\pi}_{1}` etc. instead of `\hat{\pi_{1}}`

Comment: Or you can try `\widehat{\pi_{1}}` (load `yhmath` for this).

Answer (score 3):

I assume you wish to center the hat symbols above `\pi` rather than above `\pi_1`, `\pi_{01}`, or `\pi_{11}`. If this assumption is correct, simply change your code so that only `\pi` is in the argument of `\hat`.

Some additional comments: (i) Don't load packages more than once. (ii) Since you're loading the `setspace` package, it's a bad idea to run `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}`; instead, run `\setstretch{1.5}`. (iii) There's no point in loading the `lmodern` font package if you're later going to load Times Roman text and math fonts. (iv) Unless your TeX distribution is positively ancient, it shouldn't be necessary to load the `epstopdf` package. (v) Optional: To assure that the subscripts below `\hat{\pi}` are all typeset at the same depth below the baseline, add `^{}` items to those `\hat{\pi}` instances that don't already have a superscript term.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% (simplified the preamble to load only essential packages)
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=6cm,right=2cm,vmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5} % NOT "\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}"

\usepackage{amsmath}
% 'mathptmx' is borderline obsolete
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} 

\begin{document}
\[
Q_{\mathrm{Ind}}( \pi_{01}=\pi_{11} ) = 
-2\log \Biggl[ \frac{%
  (1-\hat{\pi}^{}_1)^{T_{00}} \hat{\pi}_1^{T_{01}} 
  (1-\hat{\pi}^{}_1)^{T_{10}} \hat{\pi}_1^{T_{11}}}%
 {(1-\hat{\pi}^{}_{01})^{T_{00}} \hat{\pi}_{01}^{T_{01}} 
  (1-\hat{\pi}^{}_{11})^{T_{10}} \hat{\pi}_{11}^{T_{11}}
 } \Biggr]
\]
\end{document}
```